# Problems creating dynamic associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I want to create dynamic associative array from two array's
one array is be used  (`$l_arr`) for key and other array is used for value (`$r_arr`) when i display `$map` in output i can see there is associative array created but when i print `echo $map['key']` output is blank please help me guyz. here is the code and output,

```
<?php


$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
fscanf($handle,"%d",$n);

for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
     $arr_temp = fgets($handle);
     $l_arr[$i]= preg_replace("/[0-9,.]/", "", $arr_temp);
     $r_arr[$i]=preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $arr_temp);

}
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
$arr_temp = fgets($handle);
$op[$i]=$arr_temp;
}
          for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
    {

        $map[$l_arr[$i]]=$r_arr[$i];

     }
print_r($map);

echo "value of sam is".$map['sam'];

?>
```

and output is

```
Array
(
    [sam 
] => 99912222
    [tom 
] => 11122222
    [harry 
] => 12299933
)

value of sam is
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can probably see, there are whitespaces in your output - look at new lines after each array index. You need to `trim()` your `preg_replace()` here:

```
$l_arr[$i] = trim(preg_replace("/[0-9,.]/", "", $arr_temp));
$r_arr[$i] = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $arr_temp));
```